# Why was my answer deleted as spam / offensive?

Tags: discussion, answers, spam, deleted

I want the following answer undeleted as it clearly and demostrabely is not what it is falsely accused of !

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/131840/revisions

I have not used offensive language nor have I spammed, so why and how exactly did this get deleted after not even 1 hour of posting?!

Oh now (a few minutes after asking here) someone changed the reason of deletion to "spam or rude or abusive".

WTH is going on here?
It's not rude nor abusive either. 
Seriously people, has just anyone access to these features?

**As for Snow's absolutely inaccurate answer:**

> You accuse the OP of trolling

No direct accusation has been made.
I said "SOUNDS LIKE [OP] is trolling" and admitted right after,it"s a possible scenario.

> You helpfully suggest that the employees's children might be too "fugly" to warrant having a real photo of them on display

What's wrong with assuming someone might think a person is too ugly and decides to show more "norm conformant" people instead?
Other than the fact that this someone has issues to be addressed.

> You called the employee "an idiot"

Nope.I said:"there might be idiots out there".
Talking about at least one HYPOTHETICAL person .

I know nuances are not favoured these days but in language they're "somewhat" important,especially if the "community" has what amounts to CENSORSHIP powers !

Comment: It is rude. Someone asked a question and you said they were trolling.

Comment: @Twyxz nope.I said "SOUNDS LIKE [OP] is trolling" and admitted right after,it's a possible scenario.No direct accusation.

Comment: I am thinking maybe, just maybe that *fugly* was a bit over the top.

Comment: BTW, adding "*Sounds Like*" before your text does not mean you will be given a hall pass on the rest of the content.

Comment: @Mister Positive  It's not a definitive accusatory form but the statement of an appearence of a potential.Very different in content and intent.Changing the statement of the sentence or paragraph. As for "fugly" being over the top, that's ludicrous and I guess you might think similarly. It may be that some jump on it nowadays thanks to rampant PC culture but it won't validate any potential accusation of it being inappropriate.It's a form used to prevent profanity while still keeping the meaning and power of the intended statement.

Comment: Certainly seems a a fairly minor transgression....mentioning troll... I don't really see anything wrong with the rest. I don't see any spam content at all.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, that's why I even answered at all, giving OP the benefit of the doubt,maybe give others with similar observations an answer .but I dodn't want to completely ignore the possibility of trolling either.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I can say that the sensable boundaries I see are quite far away. I honestly see absolutely nothing remotely profane, insulting or rude in what and how I said it. If I wanted to test the waters I would have used quite different language and frankly I'm really surprised and shocked as what seems to constitute rudeness,profanity or offensive language these days. I only saw dictatorships  and ideologies using censorship this cleverly by not attacking what has been said but how it was said to silence dissident opinion. Kind of how Al Capone got brought down,for taxes.Scary new world.

Comment: @DigitalBlade969 - dictatorships. Got it. It might not be good to compare yourself to Al Capone though. Just sayin...

Comment: *sounds like you are trolling* is rhetorical subtext for *you're a troll* with the added escape clause that you will distance yourself from the taunt if the need arises.

Comment: @bruglesco no,it expresses that I have a suspicion but am not certain.Thus speaking in subjunctive or irrealis mood,stating a possibility,without the certainty of it being factual or real.But these kinds of nuances are dead in the current days of black and white and jumping to being offended to simply kill any discussion that challenges the readers / listeners views while at the same time silencing an opposing opinion.Very effective,very dangerous and very totalitarian. Case in point, my posts deletion.Not with arguments against my statements but with exaggerated outrage and misinterpretation.

Answer (score 14):

Well, let's see.

- You accuse the OP of trolling
- You helpfully suggest that the employees's children might be too "fugly" to warrant having a real photo of them on display
- You called the employee "an idiot"

The answer got flagged by the community (i.e. users).

Granted, there were some sentences in your answer that weren't offensive.

Comment: 1.No direct accusation.I said "SOUNDS LIKE OP is trolling" and admitted right after,it"s a possible scenario.2.what's wrong with assuming someone might think a person is too ugly and decides to show more "norm conformant" people instead?Other than the fact that this someone has issues to be addressed.3.nope.I said:"there might be idiots out there".Talking about a HYPOTHETICAL person.I know nuances are not favoured these days but in language they're "somewhat" important,especially if the "community" has CENSORSHIP powers ! Granted,there were some sentences in your answer that weren't incorrect.

Comment: Prefacing "sounds like" to something doesn't really change anything - accusing someone of trolling is the same as saying "you sound like you're trolling".  In any event, accusing (or suggesting) that someone is trolling is in itself a form of trolling.

Comment: The simple solution is this.  If you think that a question is a made-up or trolling question, then VTC and move on - there's absolutell no need to make the situation worse by answering it, as you only contribute to it's traffic.

Comment: oooh but it changes a lot! It's not a definitive accusatory form but the statement of an appearence of a potential.Very different in content and intent.That's what I was saying about nuance! https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sounding: "to seem like something" I had a feeling it might be trolling but I wanted to give OP the benefit of the doubt or at least a chance for others in comparable situations to see an answer to the scenario.